# ActiveRecord не сохраняет

Tags: yii

Вот такой кусочек кода, предупреждений никаких не выдается.
В модели есть поле count.
Не сохраняется. Не пойму почему.

```
$file=Files::model()->findByPk($id);   
if($file == null) {
  throw new CHttpException(404,'Не найдено');   
}
$count = $file->count;           
$count++;                             
$file->count = $count;           
$file->save();                                      
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->hostInfo."/".$file->path);
```

Answer (score 2):

save сохраняет как новую, так загруженные из БД модели. Проверьте прописано ли для этого поля правило валидации (метод rules) и еще проверьте все методы модели типа beforeValidate, beforeSave - они должны возвращать true а лучше parent::beforeSave()

Answer (score 2):

сделайте так

```
if(!$model->save())
    print_r($model->getErrors());
```

Метод покажет, есть ли ошибки при валидации.

Answer (score 0):

вы модель загрузили с базы по определенному id)
метод save - сохраняет новую (поля получены не из базы, созданую с помощью оператора new) модель в базу) читаем тут -  [абзац Обновление записи](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.ar)

тут два решения - первый юзать метод update()  или перед строкой file->save();      сбрасываем поле  CActiveRecord::isNewRecord - в false, и тогда при вызове метода save на самом деле будет вызван update

Answer (score 0):

Отключите валидацию при сохранении.

```
$file->save(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь поле `count` является у вас счетчиком.
Имейте ввиду, что правильная реализация счетчика будет такой:

```
$file=Files::model()->findByPk($id);
if($file === null) throw new CHttpException(404,'Не найдено');
$file->saveCounters(array('count'=>1));
```

Пруфлинк: http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/yii-1.1.8
Работаем со счётчиками в БД через AR

Answer (score 0):

```
if($file->save())
  good
else
 error
```

Ну так выведи ошибку которая возникает при save и тогда будем смотреть дальше.